# What is shortcut for commenting text in .txt files in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, comments

I know that there is shortcut in Eclipse Command+/ (CTRL+/) to comment line or block but not for .txt file. So how to do that instead of commenting each line manually?

Comment: Isn't the whole of a .txt file, by definition, a comment?  Just say'in.

Comment: No. So if whole .txt file is a comment than what does "#" sign do? I am working in Robot Framework where comment in .txt file does matter.

Comment: OK.  Well, you could open the .txt file  with the Java editor (right click on the file name, "Open With...Other...Java Editor") and get that effect (Command+/ toggles comments on a block of text).

Comment: Than manually add comment would be much faster C:

Comment: This sounds more like a shell script or "Robot" file than a plain text file.

Comment: Go to wiki and read about Robot Framework and how it works, better try it. In Robot Framework you actually work with Plain Text Documents.

Answer (score 2):

As @Bob Kuhar commented you can open the .txt file in Java editor. Right click on the text file, go to Open with > Other. Choose **Java Editor**  in the editor selection dialog box.

Select a single line or block of lines then press

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>  --> All line will be commented in **//** style comments(Single line comments)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> --> All line will be commented in **/*** style(Multi line comment)

Note that if you type Jay keyword like class, for, while etc then these will be highlighted in coloured text.